# Storing non-zero integers from one matrix into another

Tags: matlab, function, loops, for-loop

I'm attempting to create a loop that reads through a matrix (A) and stores the non-zero values into a new matrix (w). I'm not sure what is wrong with my code.

```
function [d,w] = matrix_check(A)
[nrow ncol] = size(A);
total = 0;
for i = 1:nrow
    for j = 1:ncol
        if A(i,j) ~= 0
            total = total + 1;
        end
    end
end
d = total;
w = [];
for i = 1:nrow
    for j = 1:ncol
        if A(i,j) ~= 0
            w = [A(i,j);w];
        end
    end
end
```

The second loop is not working (at at least it is not printing out the results of w).

Comment: Use [MATLAB's debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to step through your code and see how it's flowing.

Comment: This function works fine for me, are you calling `matrix_check` with two declared outputs? e.g. `[d, w] = matrix_check(A)`

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to see why my output is just one value. It's not printing anything out for w, just d.

Comment: When you say "at least it is not printing out the results of w", do you mean that w is empty or that you just want to see the values of w while it's being filled? In that case remove the semicolon...

Comment: Oh ok, I thought that even with the w specified in the output, it would print w even if I had included the semicolon.

Comment: Nope, the semicolon suppresses (almost) all output and when using several return values of a function only the first one is printed -- as you just saw. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`nonzeros`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html) and [`nnz`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html):

```
w = flipud(nonzeros(A)); %// flipud to achieve the same order as in your code
d = nnz(A);
```

Comment: Doh! Of course there are built-ins for that. Minor tweak, you have `d` and `w` flipped.

Answer (score 1):

The second loop is working. I'm guessing you're doing:

```
>> matrix_check(A)
```

And not:

```
>> [d, w] = matrix_check(A)
```

MATLAB will only return the first output unless otherwise specified.

As an aside, you can accomplish your task utilizing MATLAB's [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) and take advantage of the (much faster, usually) array operations rather than loops.

```
d = sum(sum(A ~= 0));
w = A(A ~= 0);
```